# Passing attribute from Terraform to Chef

Tags: chef-infra, terraform

I am trying to figure out how to pass a value from Terraform to Chef.  I have an attribute set in Terraform.

```
run_list = ['cookbook::default']
attributes_json = <<EOF
{
  "department": "CC"
}
EOF
```

Here is my Chef recipe

```
    department = ''

    if node['platform_family'] == 'windows'
      user 'test' do
        password 'hash'
        comment department
      end
      if department == 'CC'
        group 'Administrators' do
          action :modify
          members 'test'
          append true
        end
      end
    end
```

When I run Terraform, it completes successfully but the conditional for department is not met so it does not add test account to admin group.  I plugged department into the user comment as well so I could see the value (if anything).  Nothing is being passed.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I finally figured out how to get the values.  I made a single non-critical change to the Terraform json just in case I wanted to pass extra values.

```
attributes_json = <<EOF
{
  "access": {
    "department": "CC"
  }
}
EOF
```

However, I was not referencing this value correctly in Chef.

```
department = node['access']['department']

if node['platform_family'] == 'windows'
  user 'test' do
    password 'hash'
    comment department
  end
  if department == 'CC'
    group 'Administrators' do
      action :modify
      members 'test'
      append true
    end
  end
end
```

I needed to set the attribute created in Chef equal to the value coming from Terraform.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass JSON to the `json_attributes` argument in Terraform's Chef provisioner, it is cast as a hash and added to the `node` hash when passed to Chef. Therefore, your values are accessible as key-value pairs within the hash assigned to `node`, and your specific key is `department` and value is `CC`. Therefore, the lookup syntax for this in Chef (and Ruby) would be:

```
node['department']
```

Updating your code in Chef we arrive at:

```
if node['department'] == 'CC'
  group 'Administrators' do
    action :modify
    members 'test'
    append true
  end
end
```

Comment: So I changed all 3 references of department to node.default['department'].  Had to use node.default as node triggers foodcritic.  Apply works but conditional still doesn't fire.